# Why does this not generate a matrix in racket?

Tags: matrix, racket

I would like to generate a matrix (perhaps with numbers from a process, used `0` for simplification as below) in racket. I tried

```
(array (for/vector ((x (range 4)))
           (for/vector ((y (range 4)))
             0)))
```

which gives

```
(array '#(#(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0)))
```

Silly enough though,

```
(matrix? (array (for/vector ((x (range 4)))
           (for/vector ((y (range 4)))
             0))))
```

gives `#f`, and so does `(array '#(#(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0)))`. Yet

```
> (matrix? (array #(#(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0))))
#t
```

So what's going wrong with it?

---

EDIT: the matrix module is imported from `math/array` and `math/matrix`.

Comment: From where are you importing the `matrix?` procedure? is not part of the base language

Comment: @ÓscarLópez It’s math/matrix. I added this to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array` is some special magic thing which I don't understand but its body is not a general-purpose expression at all.   If you want to make an array programmatically you want something like `build-array` or `vector*->array`:

```
(define nvs (for/vector ((x (range 4)))
              (for/vector ((y (range 4)))
                0)))

(define a (vector*->array nvs number?))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `array` special form defines a new syntax, according to the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_construct.html#%28form._%28%28lib._math%2Farray..rkt%29._array%29%29) it expects "nested rows of expressions" as its argument, which is not the same as a `vector`. For example:

```
(require math/array)
(require math/matrix)

(array #[#[1]])
=> (array #[#[1]])
(matrix? (array #[#[1]]))
=> #t

(array (vector (vector 1)))
; notice the difference, there's a quote and the brackets are not square
=> (array '#(#(1)))
(matrix? (array (vector (vector 1))))
=> #f
```

To summarize: you can't use a vector of vectors as a substitute for the special syntax that `array` requires as its argument. And it's not just a matter of removing the quote and using square brackets, they're objects of different types even though they look similar when printed.